# Click on Text field should redirect to a new Page

Tags: formula-field, text, hyperlink

I have a formula field which uses Hyperlink. Click on it will navigate to a new VF Page. It is working fine. But due to some unavoidable reason I can't place that field in a page layout. I have a text field already available in that pagelayout. How should I configure it in such a way that click on text field does the same as the Formula field?

Comment: Can you use Rich Text Area field?

Comment: No, it's not supported.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Can I ask why you can't place that field in page layout?